# why vueRouter still rendering all the other components as well? (much appreciated)

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

first of all thank you,

I have clearly created three routers, and when clicked the URL is changing but the remaining two components are also getting renders.

**Also, it is not changing to that specific page. it is just showing it below other content below**

I have read and watched a few videos, can't understand what I am missing here

devtools is also for some reasons showing [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKPUq.png)
which is wierd and strange, I have stopped and restarted the serve, still problem persists.

Please help, thank you

```js
my app components :


<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div>
      <h2>Are you first time visiting?</h2>
      <router-link 
      to="/firstUser"
      > 
      Register </router-link>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Continue with registration</h2>
      <router-link to="/returningUser"> Continue </router-link>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Show all your info</h2>
      <router-link to="/registeredUser"> show </router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>

  </div>
  <router-view />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {};
  },
};
</script>

router index.js file:

import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import firstUser from '@/views/firstUser';
import returningUser from '@/views/returningUser';
import registeredUser from '@/views/registeredUser';


const routes = [{
        path: '/firstUser',
        name: 'firstUser',
        component: firstUser,

    },
    {
        path: '/returningUser',
        name: 'returningUser',
        component: returningUser,

    },
    {
        path: '/registeredUser',
        name: 'registeredUser',
        component: registeredUser,

    },

]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes
})

export default router


and one of the pages firstUser: 



<template>
  <div>
    <form class="form" @submit.prevent="registerUser">
      <h4 class="">Register</h4>
      <my-input
        v-model="this.firstName"
        type="text"
        class="input"
        placeholder="First Name"
      />
      <my-input
        v-model="this.lastName"
        type="text"
        class="input"
        placeholder="Last Name"
      />
      <myButton @click="registerUser"> Register </myButton>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import myInput from "@/components/UI/myInput.vue";
import myButton from "@/components/UI/myButton.vue";
export default {
  name: "firstUser",
  components: { myInput, myButton },
  data() {
    return {
      user: [
        {
          firstName: "",
          lastName: "",
        },
      ],
      users: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    registerUser() {
      const newUser = {
        firstName: this.firstName,
        lastName: this.lastName,
      };
      this.users.push(newUser);
      console.log(newUser);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I think you have a nesting error, the `<router-view />` should be inside the `<div id="app">`

Comment: given the fact that when i use the vue-cli it puts it bellow, i'm not sure that is the issue here

Comment: you should not "just" use push on users as it likely won't trigger the listener. You should reaffect all arrays after modifying them.

Comment: does it work by manually visiting the urls ?

Comment: @laenNoCode yes, it works. it is just not showing that particular page alone, but keeps showing the others

Comment: @Thomas I have tried it the way, you said, nothing changed in terms of rendering the page but again, like laenNoCode mentioned, it comes configured like, I put it back back

Comment: This is how it is rendering, although I wanted it to  be rendered on a totally different page: https://prnt.sc/1vbb9xn

Comment: can you post your project on github so we can reproduce ?

Comment: @Eternal you can check the demo project https://github.com/Jebasuthan/vue3-todo

Comment: @Eternal Are you looking for similar apprach https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-fermat-hgosy

Comment: @Jebasuthan yes, something like this, I studies your files, I think I must have messed it with the components files or something, here is the link to github repo
https://github.com/Eternal-uz/spa/tree/master can you please have a look?

Comment: @Jebasuthan in fact, the codesandbox project does exactly what my project is doing, it changes the url but does not change the page, should I learn more about the navigation guards or stuff like that to be able to change the page?

Comment: works fine on my end. What browser are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the Position of your router-view .A template can contain only one root element. I think that is ur case here

```js
my app components :


<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div>
      <h2>Are you first time visiting?</h2>
      <router-link 
      to="/firstUser"
      > 
      Register </router-link>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Continue with registration</h2>
      <router-link to="/returningUser"> Continue </router-link>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Show all your info</h2>
      <router-link to="/registeredUser"> show </router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
 <router-view />
  </div>
 
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {};
  },
};
</script>

router index.js file:

import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import firstUser from '@/views/firstUser';
import returningUser from '@/views/returningUser';
import registeredUser from '@/views/registeredUser';


const routes = [{
        path: '/firstUser',
        name: 'firstUser',
        component: firstUser,

    },
    {
        path: '/returningUser',
        name: 'returningUser',
        component: returningUser,

    },
    {
        path: '/registeredUser',
        name: 'registeredUser',
        component: registeredUser,

    },

]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes
})

export default router


and one of the pages firstUser: 



<template>
  <div>
    <form class="form" @submit.prevent="registerUser">
      <h4 class="">Register</h4>
      <my-input
        v-model="this.firstName"
        type="text"
        class="input"
        placeholder="First Name"
      />
      <my-input
        v-model="this.lastName"
        type="text"
        class="input"
        placeholder="Last Name"
      />
      <myButton @click="registerUser"> Register </myButton>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import myInput from "@/components/UI/myInput.vue";
import myButton from "@/components/UI/myButton.vue";
export default {
  name: "firstUser",
  components: { myInput, myButton },
  data() {
    return {
      user: [
        {
          firstName: "",
          lastName: "",
        },
      ],
      users: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    registerUser() {
      const newUser = {
        firstName: this.firstName,
        lastName: this.lastName,
      };
      this.users.push(newUser);
      console.log(newUser);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for trying, it definitely is not because of the position, as I have tried it in multiples different ways

Comment: In Vue 3 you can actually have multiple root elements, so this isn't the problem per se.